# I want more than one link hover colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

On my website, I have two sets of links but I want each set of links to have a different colour when you hover over them. So far I can only have one colour for all links on the site! 
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Give a different class to the second set of links and set the color property on hover for that class.

Comment: Give them different classes, and then use `a.class1:hover` and `a.class2:hover` selectors in the CSS.

Comment: Ignore the javascript + jquery and focus on learning how css works. <style>.set1 a{color:pink;} .set2 a{color:orange;}</style>

Answer (score 1):

Use a `class` for the links you want a different color for.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2whT/1/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">First link</a>
<a href="#" class="alt">Second link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
}

a.alt:hover {
    color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give one set of links `class="class1"`, give the other `class="class2"`. Then your CSS can contain:

```css
a.class1:hover {
    color: red;
}

a.class2:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```